# how to mix 2wifi routers in one issd?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

I have 2 wifi routers at home, with internet from two differents providers and need a repeater who mix that networks in one issd so if one of the connection fails always have internet connection, what device I need to buy?

Comment: It's not easy to mix concurrent internet connection together. The technique called bonding, and you need a device with linux kernel and other device on the server side for the same source ip.

Comment: @IporSircer the user mentions using one if the other fails - this isn't so hard, and doesn't infact need two AP's either, just a gateway that can detect if the connection is down and re-route traffic appropriately.

Comment: I am currently using Mikrotik's RB850Gx2
, but I have it configured to use external BGP. You can configure it to use internal BGP to achieve your goal.